# CRUD Actions Unrecognized slot name

Tags: vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

I want achieve the functionality what you can see in the picture however looks like `item.actions` slot is no longer available in for `v-data-table`. Could you help me how can I achieve this functionality?

[image]

```
              <div class="text-overline mb-1">Scopes</div>
              <v-data-table items-per-page="5" density="compact" :items="state.clientScopes"
                            :headers="scopeHeaders">

                <template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
                  <v-icon size="small" class="me-2">mdi-pencil</v-icon>
                  <v-icon size="small">mdi-delete</v-icon>
                </template>

              </v-data-table>
```

Comment: Isn't the screenshot directly from the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/basics/#crud-actions)? It would be weird for documentation code to not work.  Did you click the link above the table that runs the sample code in Vuetify Playground?  It definitely works. FYI `item.actions` is technically documented in the API as `item.<string>` where `<string>` is the header `key` of a specific column, so make sure you have a header defined with `key: 'actions'` and the slot will work.

Comment: Yes, you are right the header was the issue. Somehow the IDE warning lead me into a wrong direction. thank you for the help.